# How can I fix ConcurrentModificationException errors in Kafka? (0.9.0.1)

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka

I'm aware of Kafka's statement that KafkaConsumer is not thread-safe.

So I did this:  (Scala)

```
val m = Map(new TopicPartition(msg.topic(), msg.partition()) -> new OffsetAndMetadata(msg.offset()))
consumer.synchronized{ consumer.commitSync(m) }
```

I'm putting my access to consumer inside a synchronized block, but I still get ConcurrentModificationException errors on the line with consumer.commitSync(m).

**Why, and what can I do about it?**

I'm using Akka streams, so there's bound to be thread mysteries under the covers but shouldn't the synchronized block take care of this?

Comment: I guess you have multiple instances of `consumer`, so the synchronization does not work as you call `synchronized` on different objects... You need a globally shared object (ie, single instance of an dummy `Object`) that each consumer thread used to get the lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach found in the docs is to create a separate thread, just for the KafkaConsumer, and communicate with the outside work with some kind of concurrent queue.